# RecyclerView onScrolled not called when use scrollToPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` like this

```
findViewById(R.id.button_scroll_to_position).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,0);
    }
}); 

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        Log.i("TAG", "scroll " + dy);
    }
});

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    list.add("" + i);
}
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleRVAdapter(list));
mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,0);
```

However in some case `onScrolled` don't call event `RecyclerView` have scrolled (using `scrollToPositionWithOffset`).
I know the reason is when we use `scrollToPositionWithOffset` (or `scrollToPosition`) `onScrolled` only call when `firstVisibleItem` and `lastVisibleItem` change. You can see in the demo (if firstVisibleItem=2 and lastVisibleItem=5 => onScrolled not called, firstVisibleItem=2 and lastVisibleItem=6 => onScrolled will called)

Is there any trick or workaround way for always receive `onScrolled` when use `scrollToPosition`?

[image]

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: An alternate solution for the `onScrolled` issue is mentioned here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695696/5845137)

Answer (score 7):

I found that
if `RecyclerView` is scrolled (by using scrollToPosition) while `firstVisibleItem` and `lastVisibleItem` does not change **THEN**  `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` is not called but [View.OnLayoutChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html) is called.

Therefore, now I use both `OnScrollListener` and `OnLayoutChangeListener` for listening `RecyclerView` scroll.

I'm still looking for better solution

Comment: Could you find any better solution to the issue?

Comment: thanks had a similar issue, OnLayoutChangeListener helped.

Answer (score 0):

While you call `scrollToPosition()` onScroll never called.

**From the documentation**

> Convenience method to scroll to a certain position. RecyclerView does
>   not implement scrolling logic, rather forwards the call to
>   scrollToPosition(int)

So `scrollToPosition(int)` is not implementing the scrolling logic.

For more info look at this link.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)

Comment: Thank you but I have knew it, I also mention in my question. My problem is how can I receive scroll listener when use `scrollToPosition` or `scrollToPositionWithOffset`

Comment: Sorry, I come back to you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm necroing thread but just in case someone runs into it like I did...

If you don't care about animation use:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

It will trigger

```
OnScrollListener.onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
```

Comment: This question and my answer is quite long then I'm not sure 100%. In my answer, I have mention that "If RecyclerView is scrolled (by using scrollToPosition) while `firstVisibleItem` and `lastVisibleItem` not change **THEN**  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener not called". When you use `smoothScrollToPosition`, are you test the case scroll but the `firstVisibleItem` and `lastVisibleItem` not changed?

Comment: in my question, you will see, before I call `scrollToPosition`, the `firstVisibleItem` is 2 and the `lastVisibleItem` is 5, after I call `scrollToPosition`, the `firstVisibleItem` **still** 2 and the `lastVisibleItem` **still** 5. it make onScroll not called

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OnGlobalLayoutListener to to fix it.
OnGlobalLayoutListener is fixing that by making a little scroll by using scrollBy function directly on RecyclerView

```
    (binding.recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index, offset)
    binding.recyclerView.scrollBy(0, -1)
    val listener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            binding.recyclerView.scrollBy(0, 1)
            binding.recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    }
    binding.recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
```

Thanks to Jakub for help :)